# Create Runnable in Spring xml

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to create a Runnable in my spring configuration for providing to a ScheduledExecutorService bean. This Runnable should call a function on an existing bean. I can't figure out how to do this in Spring. This is what the equivalent code looks like:

```
private Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        thing.update();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring XML can only define beans from concrete classes. `Runnable` is an interface, not a concrete class.

You can write a concrete class that does what you want:

```
public class ThingUpdatingRunnable implements Runnable {
     private final Thing thing;

     public ThingUpdatingRunnable(Thing thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
          thing.update();
     }
}
```

... and define it as a bean in the normal way:

```
<bean id = "thingUpdater" class = "org.me.ThingUpdatingRunnable">
   <constructor-argument ref="thing"/>
</bean>
```

... but you should probably get into [configuring Spring through annotated Java](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html) - most Spring developers now prefer this to XML:

```
@Configuration
public class ThingUpdaterConfiguration {

     @Bean
     public Runnable thingUpdater(Thing thing) {
          return new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                    thing.update();
               }
          }
     }
}
```

(Or with Java 8:)

```
 @Bean
 public Runnable thingUpdater(Thing thing) {
      return () -> thing.update();
 }
```